# Randomly partitioning a matrix using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, partitioning

I have a matrix of data that is 130 by 2. Using MATLAB, I would like to *randomly* partition the rows into 7 sets, of roughly equal size.

Googling gave me the impression that the cvpartition command might do the trick, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. I would appreciate some guidance. I'm completely new to MATLAB.

Comment: Should all partitions have approximately the same size?

Comment: Yes. Will edit question to reflect this wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a randomized index vector: `I = randperm(130);` Since `130 = 3 * 18 + 4 * 19`, the partitions will look like

```
P1 = A(I(  1: 18), :);
P2 = A(I( 19: 36), :);
P3 = A(I( 37: 54), :);
P4 = A(I( 55: 73), :);
P5 = A(I( 74: 92), :);
P6 = A(I( 93:111), :);
P7 = A(I(112:130), :);
```

where `A` denotes the matrix containing the data to be partitioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very straightforward and to the point.